# Q:AutoMapper unable to use TypeCode in Destination

Tags: c#, automapper

I got a very strange problem,when i add a property named [IdTypeCode] with decimal type in
Destination,the Map method will throw an exception. Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks.

```
public class Source
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal IdTypeCode { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.CreateMap<Source, Destination>());
        var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
        //will throw an exception
        var dest = mapper.Map<Destination>(new Source
        {
            Id = 1
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you include the exception message, please?

Comment: ExceptionMessage:

Error mapping types.
Mapping types:
Source -> Destination
ConsoleApp1.Source -> ConsoleApp1.Destination
Type Map configuration:
Source -> Destination
ConsoleApp1.Source -> ConsoleApp1.Destination
Destination Member:
IdTypeCode

InnerExceptionMessage:

Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
TypeCode -> Decimal
System.TypeCode -> System.Decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a side-effect of AutoMapper attempting to "[flatten](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html)" the source `Id` property into the destination object.

Since your destination has the property `IdTypeCode`, AutoMapper will try to find a matching value from the source. And in this case, it seems to be picking up on the [`Type.GetTypeCode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettypecode?view=netcore-3.1) method on the `Source.Id` property, and hence trying to map a `System.TypeCode` to a `decimal`. This can be seen in the exception that's thrown:

```
Destination Member: IdTypeCode

 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types: 
TypeCode -> Decimal 
System.TypeCode -> System.Decimal
```

This can be verified by changing the type of `Destination.IdTypeCode` to `System.TypeCode`:

```
public class Source
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TypeCode IdTypeCode { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.CreateMap<Source, Destination>());
        var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
        //will throw an exception
        var dest = mapper.Map<Destination>(new Source
        {
            Id = 1
        });

        Console.WriteLine(dest.IdTypeCode);
    }
}
```

which causes the mapping to succeed and the `Destination.IdTypeCode` getting mapped with the value `Int32`.

---

With that said, aside from changing the name of the property, one easy solution is just to ignore that property on the destination:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
    {
        c.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(d => d.IdTypeCode, opt => opt.Ignore());
    });
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.gettypecode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: thanks for your answer,I noticed that it only throw exception when type is decimal and name endwith TypeCode, if i change code as below:

    public class Source
    {
        public string Card { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public string Card { get; set; }
        public decimal CardTypeCode { get; set; }
    }

it will throw a same exception,  change property's name or type or ignore map will solve this issue, but in my project, class Destination is generated by database table schema, so is there any other solution for this issue?

Comment: it works, but for every Destination class i need to check it properties, make sure Ignore the property which name end with TypeCode

Comment: You can simply disable the feature, `configuration.ShouldMapMethod = _=>false;`.

Answer (score 0):

according to Lucian's answer, i change my code as below,it works well

```
    public class Source
    {
        public string Card { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public string Card { get; set; }
        public decimal CardTypeCode { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(configure =>
            {
                //set this func
                configure.ShouldMapMethod = _ => false;
                configure.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
            });
            var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
            var dest = mapper.Map<Destination>(new Source
            {
                Card = "1"
            });
        }
    }
```